# How to deploy jbpm-console 3.3.1 on jboss web server3.0.0 beta-1

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jbpm, jboss-web

I want to deploy jbpm-console on jboss web server,
but the following error message appears.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

2010-01-22 08:11:21,416 ERROR [org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap] (Thread-2) Failed to load profile: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfsfile:/E:/app/jboss-web-3.0.0-beta-1-zip/jboss-web-3.0.0-beta-1/server/default/deploy/jsf-console.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/E:/app/jboss-web-3.0.0-beta-1-zip/jboss-web-3.0.0-beta-1/server/default/deploy/jsf-console.war/ deployment failed

Answer (score 0):

You are really trying experimental things here and, to be honest, I wonder why you're not using one of the [supported container](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/jBPM3TargetContainers) (well, the matrix is actually not up to date and if I remember well, the installer of jBPM 3.3.1 suggests JBoss 4.2.2, JBoss 4.2.3, JBoss 5.0.0).

Anyway, JBoss Web being based on Tomcat, did you try to follow the steps of [JbpmOnTomcat](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JbpmOnTomcat)? It seems that you need to build a jbpm-console.war customized for deployment on TC. There is no guarantee that all this will work though. If it doesn't, just use a supported platform.

Comment: Thank your answer,Pascal.I tried second way to deploy that solve this issue,and done.

Comment: @BeckWu You're welcome. If this solved your issue, then please accept my answer (the green tick on its left). And BTW: the common way of recognizing a good answer is upvoting it ;-)